# How to achieve bulk update ( contact object) to Salesforce from Mule 4 API

Tags: salesforce, mule4, mule-component

I have a requirement to update employee fields in salesforce (update only, not creating a new one if not present - upsert) using contact object/type.

I am able to update it successfully using the Mule flow and connectors shown in the screenshot below, however I want to do the update in Bulk (for 200 records at once).

Currently I am calling query connector to getting the salesforce id, then construct the payload and do the actual update. Is there any way to update this in a single call? I know there is one to one mapping of employee id to salesforce id, but can we achieve it using a single connector? The reason we want to move to this approach is - since the records are getting more and more every day, its taking longer time and make it more efficient.

Let me know if anything in unclear in the question

[image]

Comment: Do you have an array of `employeeId`s?

Comment: Yes Harshank, we receive data (JSON response) from the source stream in the form of an array of objects as shown below. But when we update this info to salesforce we need to pass each one of them to the above flow reference as shown in the screenshot attached before. 
[{
employeeid: 345997,
....
},
{
employeeid: 3245678,
....
}]

Comment: Okay. Now if the employeeID is one to one mapping with Salesforce record id, is the `employeeId` configured as a "unique External ID"?

Comment: Also please add xml code along with the screenshot of the flow. I want to understand if you are querying using array or what but i am unable to get that info. [Always post the code as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10946202)

Comment: Also please add xml code along with the screenshot of the flow. I want to understand if you are querying using array or what but i am unable to get that info. [Always post the code as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10946202)

Comment: If the field is unique, marked as external id - you should consider using upsert for this anyway. You can block the insert part of it by not populating a required field (on contact for example lastname) or some smart validation rule. Extra network traffic to pull the IDs first and map stuff is bit wasteful, overengineered

Comment: Instead of using Salesforce Update you can make use of the Bulk API (https://docs.mulesoft.com/salesforce-connector/10.18/salesforce-connector-reference#createJobBulkApiV2)

Answer (score 0):

The code will require some refactoring but if you want to update records in salesforce in bulk, the best approach is to use the [Bulk APIs v2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm)

Take a look at salesforce:upsert connector: https://docs.mulesoft.com/salesforce-connector/10.12/salesforce-connector-reference#upsert

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. Perhaps a code sample could be included?